# How can I execute syncronized this gulpfile

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, gulp, synchronization

The problem is that it does not finish generating the resources with the command 'ionic resources', and copying the images, which is already trying to compile. I don't want to use a timeout

el problema es que no termina de generar los recursos con el comando 'ionic resources', y copiar las imagenes, que ya esta tratando de compilar. No quiero usar timeouts

```
gulp.task('ionicResources', function () {
   gulputil.log(cp.execSync("ionic resources").toString('ascii'))
});

gulp.task('copiarAplatformRes', function () {
   gulp.src('./resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png')
      .pipe(rename({basename: 'icon'}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest("./platforms/android/res/mipmap-ldpi"));
});

gulp.task('compile', function () {
    gulputil.log(cp.execSync("cordova build --release adroid").toString('ascii'))
});

gulp.task("build-android", ['ionicResources', 'copiarAplatformRes','compile'],function () {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) or better yet gulp 4.0 to run your tasks in series.  Alternatively, you could make your 'copiarAplatformRes' task dependent on your 'ionicResources' task by

```
gulp.task('copiarAplatformRes', ['ionicResources'], function () {
  return gulp.src('./resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png')
  etc....
```

and add similar return statements to all your tasks.